# Why does adding one line to this SQL Server CTE expression change result

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I am trying to create a CTE (common table expression) to create a manifest BOM (Bill of Materials). I.e. a query descends through an entire BOM and summarise the quantity of each unique part.

I also need to return some data about the BOM items.

I am trying to add a calculated field to show if the BOM item is an assembly or not, i.e. If it also has bom entries.  What am I doing wrong?

The database is Aras Innovator, which uses SQL Server.

The records structure is

```
<Part_Id> - <source_id : Bom Entry : related_id> - <Part_Id>
```

So there are essentially two tables. Though the query also returns data from other related tables.

The first query works, but when I try and add the relationship showing the part is an assembly, the sum becomes wrongs and the wrong number of items is returned.

```
<!-- language: lang-sql -->
WITH RecursiveBOM(source_id, related_id, quantity) AS
(
  SELECT pbom.SOURCE_ID, pbom.RELATED_ID, pbom.QUANTITY
    FROM innovator.PART_BOM AS pbom
    WHERE SOURCE_ID = '82FD83221C5946F0A70CADD328BDB6CA'

  UNION ALL

  SELECT pbom.SOURCE_ID, pbom.RELATED_ID, pbom.QUANTITY
    FROM innovator.PART_BOM AS pbom
    INNER JOIN RecursiveBOM rbom ON rbom.RELATED_ID = pbom.SOURCE_ID
)
SELECT
  rp.MAKE_BUY as MAKE_BUY,
  rp.ITEM_NUMBER AS PN,
  rp.NAME AS NAME,
  sum(RecursiveBOM.quantity) as Total,
  mp.ITEM_NUMBER as MPN,
  man.NAME as MANUFACTURER,
  vp.CATALOG_NUMBER as SPN,
  ven.NAME as SUPPLIER,      
  CAST(CASE WHEN count(cp.RELATED_ID)>0 THEN 'Yes' ELSE 'No' END AS TEXT) AS HAS_CAD,

FROM RecursiveBOM

INNER JOIN innovator.PART sp ON RecursiveBOM.source_id = sp.ID
INNER JOIN innovator.PART rp ON RecursiveBOM.related_id = rp.ID

--Manufacturer Part
LEFT JOIN innovator.PART_AML aml ON aml.SOURCE_ID = rp.ID
LEFT JOIN innovator.MANUFACTURER_PART mp ON aml.related_ID = mp.ID
LEFT JOIN innovator.MANUFACTURER man on mp.MANUFACTURER = man.ID

--Supplier
LEFT JOIN innovator.VENDOR_PART vp ON mp.ID = vp.RELATED_ID
LEFT JOIN innovator.VENDOR ven ON vp.SOURCE_ID = ven.ID

--Has drawings
LEFT JOIN innovator.CAD_PART cp ON cp.SOURCE_ID = rp.ID

--Don't decend into PCBA
WHERE sp.classification NOT LIKE '%PCBA%'

--Collect the results 
GROUP BY
  rp.ITEM_NUMBER,
  mp.ITEM_NUMBER,
  rp.NAME,
  man.NAME,
  vp.CATALOG_NUMBER,
  ven.NAME,
  cp.RELATED_ID,
  rp.MAKE_BUY
```

I've added only two lines, which are

```
...
CAST(CASE WHEN count(bom.RELATED_ID)>0 THEN 'Yes' ELSE 'No' END as TEXT) AS IS_ASSY`
...
--Is Assembly
LEFT JOIN innovator.PART_BOM bom ON bom.SOURCE_ID = rp.ID
...
```

This produces the wrong sums:

```
<!-- language: lang-sql -->
WITH RecursiveBOM(source_id, related_id, quantity) AS
(
  SELECT pbom.SOURCE_ID, pbom.RELATED_ID, pbom.QUANTITY
    FROM innovator.PART_BOM AS pbom
    WHERE SOURCE_ID = '82FD83221C5946F0A70CADD328BDB6CA'

  UNION ALL

  SELECT pbom.SOURCE_ID, pbom.RELATED_ID, pbom.QUANTITY
    FROM innovator.PART_BOM AS pbom
    INNER JOIN RecursiveBOM rbom ON rbom.RELATED_ID = pbom.SOURCE_ID
)
SELECT
  rp.MAKE_BUY as MAKE_BUY,
  rp.ITEM_NUMBER AS PN,
  rp.NAME AS NAME,
  sum(RecursiveBOM.quantity) as Total,
  mp.ITEM_NUMBER as MPN,
  man.NAME as MANUFACTURER,
  vp.CATALOG_NUMBER as SPN,
  ven.NAME as SUPPLIER,      
  CAST(CASE WHEN count(cp.RELATED_ID)>0 THEN 'Yes' ELSE 'No' END AS TEXT) AS HAS_CAD,
  CAST(CASE WHEN count(bom.RELATED_ID)>0 THEN 'Yes' ELSE 'No' END as TEXT) AS IS_ASSY
  FROM RecursiveBOM

INNER JOIN innovator.PART sp ON RecursiveBOM.source_id = sp.ID
INNER JOIN innovator.PART rp ON RecursiveBOM.related_id = rp.ID

--Manufacturer Part
LEFT JOIN innovator.PART_AML aml ON aml.SOURCE_ID = rp.ID
LEFT JOIN innovator.MANUFACTURER_PART mp ON aml.related_ID = mp.ID
LEFT JOIN innovator.MANUFACTURER man on mp.MANUFACTURER = man.ID

--Supplier
LEFT JOIN innovator.VENDOR_PART vp ON mp.ID = vp.RELATED_ID
LEFT JOIN innovator.VENDOR ven ON vp.SOURCE_ID = ven.ID

--Has drawings
LEFT JOIN innovator.CAD_PART cp ON cp.SOURCE_ID = rp.ID

--Is Assembly
LEFT JOIN innovator.PART_BOM bom ON bom.SOURCE_ID = rp.ID

--Don't decend into PCBA
WHERE sp.classification NOT LIKE '%PCBA%'

--Collect the results 
GROUP BY
  rp.ITEM_NUMBER,
  mp.ITEM_NUMBER,
  rp.NAME,
  man.NAME,
  vp.CATALOG_NUMBER,
  ven.NAME,
  cp.RELATED_ID,
  rp.MAKE_BUY
```

Comment: My guess would be that `PART_BOM` is a 1-n relationship to `PART`, So when you join to it you are duplicating rows, and making the sum incorrect

Comment: I should probably re-phrase the question slightly, perhaps it should read "How do I get what is intended"

Answer (score 1):

There are two possible alternative solutions which should be a bit cleaner:

1) Use a sub-select.  This results in the query:

```
...
SELECT
  rp.MAKE_BUY as MAKE_BUY,
  rp.ITEM_NUMBER AS PN,
  rp.NAME AS NAME,
  sum(RecursiveBOM.quantity) as Total,
  mp.ITEM_NUMBER as MPN,
  man.NAME as MANUFACTURER,
  vp.CATALOG_NUMBER as SPN,
  ven.NAME as SUPPLIER,      
  CAST(CASE WHEN count(cp.RELATED_ID)>0 THEN 'Yes' ELSE 'No' END AS TEXT) AS HAS_CAD,
  (select count(*) from innovator.part_bom bom where bom.source_id = rp.ID) AS IS_ASSY
FROM RecursiveBOM
...
```

2) Chain the CTE expressions with the resulting query being:

```
WITH RecursiveBOM(source_id, related_id, quantity) AS
(
  SELECT pbom.SOURCE_ID, pbom.RELATED_ID, pbom.QUANTITY
    FROM innovator.PART_BOM AS pbom
    WHERE SOURCE_ID = '82FD83221C5946F0A70CADD328BDB6CA'

  UNION ALL

  SELECT pbom.SOURCE_ID, pbom.RELATED_ID, pbom.QUANTITY
    FROM innovator.PART_BOM AS pbom
    INNER JOIN RecursiveBOM rbom ON rbom.RELATED_ID = pbom.SOURCE_ID
), grouping as (
    SELECT
      rp.MAKE_BUY as MAKE_BUY,
      rp.ITEM_NUMBER AS PN,
      rp.NAME AS NAME,
      sum(RecursiveBOM.quantity) as Total,
      mp.ITEM_NUMBER as MPN,
      man.NAME as MANUFACTURER,
      vp.CATALOG_NUMBER as SPN,
      ven.NAME as SUPPLIER,      
      CAST(CASE WHEN count(cp.RELATED_ID)>0 THEN 'Yes' ELSE 'No' END AS TEXT) AS HAS_CAD,
      rp.id related_id
    FROM RecursiveBOM

INNER JOIN innovator.PART sp ON RecursiveBOM.source_id = sp.ID
INNER JOIN innovator.PART rp ON RecursiveBOM.related_id = rp.ID

--Manufacturer Part
LEFT JOIN innovator.PART_AML aml ON aml.SOURCE_ID = rp.ID
LEFT JOIN innovator.MANUFACTURER_PART mp ON aml.related_ID = mp.ID
LEFT JOIN innovator.MANUFACTURER man on mp.MANUFACTURER = man.ID

--Supplier
LEFT JOIN innovator.VENDOR_PART vp ON mp.ID = vp.RELATED_ID
LEFT JOIN innovator.VENDOR ven ON vp.SOURCE_ID = ven.ID

--Has drawings
LEFT JOIN innovator.CAD_PART cp ON cp.SOURCE_ID = rp.ID

--Don't decend into PCBA
WHERE sp.classification NOT LIKE '%PCBA%'

--Collect the results 
GROUP BY
  rp.ITEM_NUMBER,
  mp.ITEM_NUMBER,
  rp.NAME,
  man.NAME,
  vp.CATALOG_NUMBER,
  ven.NAME,
  cp.RELATED_ID,
  rp.MAKE_BUY,
  rp.id
)
select g.make_buy
  , g.pn
  , g.name
  , g.total
  , g.mpn
  , g.manufacturer
  , g.spn
  , g.supplier
  , g.has_cad
  , CASE WHEN count(bom.id) > 0 then 'Yes' ELSE 'No' END as is_assy
from grouping g
LEFT JOIN innovator.PART_BOM bom ON bom.SOURCE_ID = g.related_id
group by g.make_buy
  , g.pn
  , g.name
  , g.total
  , g.mpn
  , g.manufacturer
  , g.spn
  , g.supplier
  , g.has_cad
```

Answer (score 0):

I've found a way to get what I want, as such I am adding it as an answer. But it does not look elegant, is there another way?

On reading the question [Insert into a Temp Table in a CTE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23158917/insert-into-a-temp-table-in-a-cte) I realised that I could prevent the row duplication by first collecting the result into a temporary table, then making the relationship to the BOM.

I'm sure there is a better way....

```
<!-- language: lang-sql -->
create table #TempTable (
  id varchar(32),
  make_buy varchar(100),
  pn varchar(100),
  name varchar(100),
  total int,
  mpn varchar(100),
  manufacturer varchar(100),
  spn varchar(100),
  supplier varchar(100),
  has_cad varchar(100));


WITH RecursiveBOM(source_id, related_id, quantity, prev,next) AS
(
  SELECT pbom.SOURCE_ID, pbom.RELATED_ID, pbom.QUANTITY,0,0
  FROM innovator.PART_BOM AS pbom
  WHERE SOURCE_ID = '82FD83221C5946F0A70CADD328BDB6CA'

  UNION ALL

  SELECT pbom.SOURCE_ID, pbom.RELATED_ID, pbom.QUANTITY, next, prev
  FROM innovator.PART_BOM AS pbom
  INNER JOIN RecursiveBOM rbom ON rbom.RELATED_ID = pbom.SOURCE_ID
)

INSERT INTO #TempTable (id, make_buy, pn, name, total, mpn, manufacturer, spn, supplier, has_cad)

SELECT
  rp.ID,
  rp.MAKE_BUY as MAKE_BUY,
  rp.ITEM_NUMBER AS PN,
  rp.NAME AS NAME,
  sum(RecursiveBOM.quantity) as Total,
  mp.ITEM_NUMBER as MPN,
  man.NAME as MANUFACTURER,
  vp.CATALOG_NUMBER as SPN,
  ven.NAME as SUPPLIER,
  CAST(CASE WHEN count(cp.RELATED_ID)>0 THEN 'Yes' ELSE 'No' END AS TEXT) AS HAS_CAD

FROM RecursiveBOM

INNER JOIN innovator.PART sp ON RecursiveBOM.source_id = sp.ID
INNER JOIN innovator.PART rp ON RecursiveBOM.related_id = rp.ID

--Manufacturer Part
LEFT JOIN innovator.PART_AML aml ON aml.SOURCE_ID = rp.ID
LEFT JOIN innovator.MANUFACTURER_PART mp ON aml.related_ID = mp.ID
LEFT JOIN innovator.MANUFACTURER man on mp.MANUFACTURER = man.ID

--Supplier
LEFT JOIN innovator.VENDOR_PART vp ON mp.ID = vp.RELATED_ID
LEFT JOIN innovator.VENDOR ven ON vp.SOURCE_ID = ven.ID

--Has drawings
LEFT JOIN innovator.CAD_PART cp ON cp.SOURCE_ID = rp.ID

--Don't decend into PCBA
WHERE sp.classification NOT LIKE '%PCBA%'

--Collect the results
GROUP BY
  rp.ID,
  rp.ITEM_NUMBER,
  mp.ITEM_NUMBER,
  rp.NAME,
  man.NAME,
  vp.CATALOG_NUMBER,
  ven.NAME,
  cp.RELATED_ID,
  rp.MAKE_BUY

SELECT
  #TempTable.*,
  CAST(CASE WHEN count(bom.RELATED_ID)>0 THEN 'Yes' ELSE 'No' END as TEXT) AS IS_ASSY

FROM #TempTable

--Is Asseembly
LEFT JOIN innovator.PART_BOM as bom on bom.SOURCE_ID = #TempTable.id

--Collect the results
GROUP BY
  #TempTable.id,
  #TempTable.make_buy,
  #TempTable.pn,
  #TempTable.name,
  #TempTable.total,
  #TempTable.mpn,
  #TempTable.manufacturer,
  #TempTable.spn,
  #TempTable.supplier,
  #TempTable.has_cad

DROP TABLE #TempTable
```